# How to connect with SQLConnect from ODBC?

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server with ODBC and C++ but It can't connect I don't know why. The DSN is
already set in User DSN list.

- Windows 10 64 bits
- Compiler: VC++ 2010
- ODBC version: 2017.175.02.01
- SQL Server 2019

```
# include "stdafx.h"
# include <windows.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <sql.h>
# include <sqlext.h>
# include <iostream>
 
int main( )
{
    HENV henv;
    HDBC hdbc;
    RETCODE rc;
    
    SQLAllocEnv(&henv);
    SQLAllocConnect(henv, &hdbc);
 
    /* Connect to the database using the ODBC DSN definition. */
    rc = SQLConnect( hdbc,     /* Connection handle */
        (SQLWCHAR*)"db1",      /* The ODBC DSN definition */
        SQL_NTS,               /* This is a null-terminated string */
        NULL,                  /* No username required */
        0,                     /* This is a null-terminated string */
        NULL,                  /* No password required */
        0);                    /* This is a null-terminated string */

    if ((rc != SQL_SUCCESS) && (rc != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    {
        SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
        SQLFreeEnv(henv);
        std::cout << "FAIL\n";
    }
    else{
        SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
        SQLFreeEnv(henv);
        std::cout << "YEA! \n";
    }

    /* Exit this program. */
    system("pause");
    return( 0 );
}
```

Solution:
Need to declare the variable type and set its value before give it to SQLConnect.
Thanks to PaulMcKenzie.

```
    SQLWCHAR name [] = L"db1";
    
    rc = SQLConnect( hdbc,     /* Connection handle */
        name,                  /* The ODBC DSN definition */
        SQL_NTS,               /* This is a null-terminated string */
        NULL,                  /* No username required */
        0,                     /* This is a null-terminated string */
        NULL,                  /* No password required */
        0);                    /* This is a null-terminated string */
```

Comment: You should issue calls to [SQLGetDiagRec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdiagrec-function?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the error.   Also, `(SQLWCHAR*)"db1"` looks wrong as it seems you are trying to "convert" a narrow string to a wide string, and casting does not convert.  If you removed that `SQLWCHAR*` cast, what error does the compiler give you?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [4]' to 'SQLWCHAR *'

Comment: Well maybe that's why it fails to connect.  You are giving the function a bogus string.  The function wants a wide string, so give it one: `L"db1"`, without casting, or `SQLWCHAR name [] = L"db1"`; and then give the function `name`.

Comment: Basically, never cast character types -- doing so is a sign that things will go wrong.  Use the character type that the function is requiring, without doing any casts.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie omg SQLWCHAR name [] = L"db1"; worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not do what you think it does:

`(SQLWCHAR*)"db1",`

If `SQLWCHAR*` is a pointer to a wide-character, then casting a non-wide string-literal will not produce the results desired, since casting will not magically convert the non-wide string literal to a wide string.  The ODBC function is failing due to the `"db1"` string ending up incorrect in some way when the function receives the string.

---

The proper way to deal with this is first, get the code to compile without any string-type to string-type casts.  Casting string types is a sign that something may go wrong.  Use the string type that the function requires.

This goes for any application -- if you're casting string types, you better know exactly what you're doing, as you may be circumventing C++'s type-safety by issuing a C-style cast to stifle the compiler error.

In this case, the string type is `SQLWCHAR`, thus creating a string (in this case, modifiable since the it isn't a `const` pointer) can be done:

`SQLWCHAR name []  = L"db1";`

and then the function will not need a cast on the second argument:

```
rc = SQLConnect( hdbc,     /* Connection handle */
    name,                  /* The ODBC DSN definition */
    SQL_NTS,               /* This is a null-terminated string */
    NULL,                  /* No username required */
    0,                     /* This is a null-terminated string */
    NULL,                  /* No password required */
    0);
```